# Como leer un archivo dentro de un servlet desde un jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Estoy haciendo una aplicación donde debo subir un archivo al servidor, lo cual ya  hice pero no se como leerlo dentro de un servlet y mostrar su contenido.

Este es el jsp:

```
<h1>Subir archivos</h1>
<form method="post" action="verif" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Formulario de subida</legend>
        <input type="file" name="files" id="files" multiple/>
        <button type="submit">Subir</button>    
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

El servlet

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();
    for(Part part : parts) {
            part.write((String) getFileName(part));
    }

}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}


 public String getFileName(Part part) {
    String contentHeader = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    String[] subHeaders = contentHeader.split(";");
    for(String current : subHeaders) {
        if(current.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            int pos = current.indexOf('=');
            String fileName = current.substring(pos+1);
            return fileName.replace("\"", "");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Buenas, por favor agrega el código que tienes de este modo podemos "ayudarte" y no "hacer por ti" lo que debes realizar.